# Android: Landscape layouts not being used

Tags: android

In my application I have one Main activity that sets up a tabbed ViewPager with three different fragments, each one with it's own layout and class. I've created landscape versions of each layout file and placed them all in res/layout-land. But when I run the app and switch orientations, the landscape layout isn't being used?

MainActivity:

```
package me.zaydbille.utilitywatch;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Tab and ViewPager variables
    Toolbar             toolbar;
    ViewPager           pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter    adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout    tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[]={"Coin Flip", "Counter", "Choice"};
    int numTabs = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, numTabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Counter Fragment helper methods
    public void addCount() {
        Preferences.setIntPref(this, Preferences.getIntPref(this) + 1);
    }

    public void clearCount() { Preferences.setIntPref(this, 0); }

    public int getCount() { return Preferences.getIntPref(this); }

    // Choice Fragment helper methods
    public void saveList(ArrayList<String> list){ Preferences.saveList(this, list); }
    public ArrayList<String> getList() { return Preferences.getList(this); }
}
```

Fragment 1:

```
package me.zaydbille.utilitywatch;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.Random;

public class CoinFlip extends Fragment {

    Button      flipButton;
    Random      randomizer;
    ImageView   mSpinningCoin;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coin_flip,container,false);

        flipButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.flipButton);
        mSpinningCoin = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.coin_spinning);

        flipButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                randomizer = new Random();
                int number = randomizer.nextInt(2);

                if (number == 0) { // Heads
                    ((AnimationDrawable) mSpinningCoin.getBackground()).stop();
                    mSpinningCoin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.coin_spin_heads);
                    ((AnimationDrawable) mSpinningCoin.getBackground()).start();
                } else if (number == 1) { // Tails
                    ((AnimationDrawable) mSpinningCoin.getBackground()).stop();
                    mSpinningCoin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.coin_spin_tails);
                    ((AnimationDrawable) mSpinningCoin.getBackground()).start();
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

Fragment 1's layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimaryLight">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coin_spinning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/coin_spin_heads"
            android:contentDescription="@string/coinDescription" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/flipButtonText"
            android:id="@+id/flipButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="me.zaydbille.utilitywatch" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HelpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_help"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="me.zaydbille.utilitywatch.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"` you are saying that you do **not** want the system to do any of its default behavior when these configuration changes happen. This includes changing any layouts. **Remove that line** or actually [handle the change yourself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this piece of code from your AppManifest.xml:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
```

This disables your activity to change its orientation. Removing that will fix it.